# change active class of menu item

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am currently working on a practice exam making a car rental website. Me and my friend who are working together. Beginning to make an admin page I came to an issue changing the active class on a menu item. tried much, but no succes yet. My question is how can I change the active class on a menu item with Javscript?

The code below is from the nav.php file which is included in the admin page php file

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rent an Electric</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
            <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
                <a class="nav-link" href="admin-page-2.php">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
                    <span class="nav-link-text">
                Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Wagenpark">
                <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('wagenpark')" href="page_admin.php?wagenpark">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></i>
                    <span class="nav-link-text">
                Wagenpark</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Gebruikers">
                <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('gebruikers')" href="page_admin.php?gebruikers">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
                    <span class="nav-link-text">
                Gebruikers</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Klanten">
                <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('klanten')" href="page_admin.php?klanten">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-child"></i>
                    <span class="nav-link-text">
                Klanten</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Facturen">
                <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('facturen')" href="page_admin.php?facturen">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>
                    <span class="nav-link-text">
                Facturen</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>
                    Uitloggen</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
    function loadQueryResult(name) {
        $('.container-fluid').load('includes/admin-page/pages/'+ name +'.php');
        return false;
    }

    //Hier moet nog een function komen voor het aanpassen van de li class naar active
    $('.navbar > ul.nav li a').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When do you want the menu item to become active and when do you want to remove this active class. Normally u could use jQuery's `removeClass` and `addClass`. https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/, https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I want the menu item to be active if I have loaded that page. I think that a issue might be caused by the function loadQueryResult. This function loads the content of a page in the container fluid. I'm not 100% sure this is the cause of the problems

Comment: This is what I am currently seeing in the console: admin-page-2.php:100 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at admin-page-2.php:100 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with jquery. Set up a default `.active` class on one of the elements in the navbar, then you can [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and then [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) with jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav li a').click(function(e) {

    $('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');

    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
nav ul li.active span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rent an Electric</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
      <li class="nav-item active" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
          <span class="nav-link-text">
                Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Wagenpark">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('wagenpark')" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-car"></i>
          <span class="nav-link-text">
                Wagenpark</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Gebruikers">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('gebruikers')" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
          <span class="nav-link-text">
                Gebruikers</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Klanten">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('klanten')" href="page_admin.php?klanten">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-child"></i>
          <span class="nav-link-text">
                Klanten</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Facturen">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="return loadQueryResult('facturen')" href="page_admin.php?facturen">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>
          <span class="nav-link-text">
                Facturen</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i> Uitloggen
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Try it out in fullscreen.

Comment: thank you very much for providing this answer. This did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simply use the jQuery add and remove class functions.

Adding a class:

```
var $element = $('.nav-link')[0]; // 0 being the index of the nav-links found
$element.addClass('active');
```

Removing a class:

```
var $element = $('.nav-link')[0];
$element.removeClass('active');
```

You could also do something a little more sassy ;)

```
function ToggleActive(link)
{
    var $element = $('.nav-link[href="'+link+'"]');
    $element.addClass('active');
}

ToggleActive('admin-page-2.php');
```

The `ToggleActive()` function takes the link as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ik merk op dat er Nederlandse comments staan en zal dus bij deze snel even in het Nederlands verder helpen.

Bij onderstaande regel wordt op hetzelfde element de active class verwijderd en terug toegevoegd.

$this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');

Wat je echter beter kunt doen is op alle items de active class te verwijderen en enkel op het geclickte element hem terug toe voegen.

bv:

```
  $('.navbar > ul.nav li a').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        for ( var i = 0; i < navlink.length;i++){
        var $element = $('.nav-link')[i]; 
        $element.removeClass('active');
        }

        $this.parent().siblings().addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use php to add the name of the active page #home

@php

```
<?php
 $active = 'home';
?>
```

@js

```
var active="<?php echo $active;?>";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#"+active).addClass("active");
});
```

if you use php to load the page